# How can I convert Gmail from standard view to basic HTML view?

Tags: gmail

How can I convert Gmail from standard view to basic HTML view permanently? A while ago there was an option at the bottom allowing me to do so, but now it is gone.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The direct link to basic HTML view is: https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html&zy=h

From the [Gmail help page](http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=15049).

** update: if you sign out (of standard view) then sign back in, a link appears in the lower right while your inbox loading screen is up. Not as convenient as having the link permanently available below your inbox, I agree -- but better than using that awkward direct link perhaps.

Addition to above:  Once you are signed into basic gmail using above info, click on the "basic view" option at the top right on your Inbox page.  This will convert you to basic permanently, or until you want to change back to standard.

Comment: `ui=html` is the param that tells Gmail to use the basic HTML layout (ui = user interface). `zy=h`, I have no idea.

Comment: Thanks! Can I append that to any links? For example, http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/24763/how-can-i-convert-gmail-to-from-standard-view-to-basic-html-view/24765#comment18934_24765?ui=html doesn't make any change.

Comment: @Tim: Uh...no. Not unless the site has code that acts on that URL parameter.

Comment: @Tim No, that's specific for Gmail. The URL parameters are specific for every single web app/site. The fact that some might work from one app to another is pure coincidence.

Comment: Thanks, Alex and @Al! I wonder if I can know what URL parameters are general?

Comment: @Tim What do you mean by ˝general˝? Ones that work for every app/site? There is no such thing.

Comment: Yes, that is what I meant. How is that implemented in programs?

Comment: @Tim They are called GET parameters. See [this Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Query_string) article an [this](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5998425/198836) Stackoverflow question.

Comment: It's too bad that the link to basic html only appears for a split second...

Comment: https://support.google.com/mail/answer/15049?ctx=gmail

Answer (score 3):

This link also works (at least [since 2012](http://jussi.ruokomaki.fi/tech/323/direct-link-to-html-gmail/), still working today) and *could possibly* be easier to remember than the other `?ui=html` link - just add **`/h/`** instead.

http://mail.google.com/mail/h/

It seems to redirect to https anyway, or just use https:

https://mail.google.com/mail/h/

---

Also, the other link will work without the `&zy=h` part, also maybe easier to remember:

https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html

Comment: What should I prefix to `gmail.com/`?

Comment: @Pacerier Any of the url's still work, the http still redirects to https, and just to recap the https links are `https://mail.google.com/mail/h/` and `https://mail.google.com/mail/?ui=html`